# UDP client across NAT could not receive data from server

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I'm trying to have a two way communication using UDP between a server (on public IP) and a client(across a NAT). My logic says that if server sends some data to the IP and the port it received the packet from, the client should still get it, because NAT would have the mapping to send the packet to the client ultimately.

Client has 2 processes, one to send packets, another process to receive the data. Server keeps on waiting for data, and if it gets data, it sends data back to the Port and IP where from the data was received.

Client code below:

client_recv.py

```
import socket
import sys

UDP_IP = '0.0.0.0'#my ip address in the local network
UDP_PORT = 5000

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print ("received message:" + data)
```

client_send.py

```
import socket
import time
import sys

UDP_IP = 'XXXXXXX.com'#external server IP address
UDP_PORT = 4000
MESSAGE = "Hi!"

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5000))
i = 0
while True:
    sock.sendto(MESSAGE + ' # ' + str(i), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
    time.sleep(1)
    i = i + 1
```

The server (on XXXXX.com - public IP) gets the packets, but not the client. Below is the code to receive and send packets on server:

server_send_recv.py

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 4000))

while True:
    data, inetaddr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print('Received ' + data)
    (ip, port) = inetaddr
    print("IP:"+str(ip)+",Port:"+str(port))
    sock.sendto('Hi From Server (against ' + data + ')', (ip, port))
```

**EDIT 1:**

As already stated in the answer, the same socket has to be used, so I did the following, and it worked. However, I'm still not clear why a different socket (client_recv), which was bound to the same Port on client would not work. Since the same ports are being reused, the client_recv should have worked right? Why did it fail, and what made the same socket to send and receive on client work?

client_send_recv.py

```
import socket
import time
import sys

UDP_IP = 'twig-me.com'#external server IP address
UDP_PORT = 4000
MESSAGE = "Hi!"

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5000))
i = 0
while True:
    print ("Sending message:" + str(i))
    sock.sendto(MESSAGE + ' # ' + str(i), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
    time.sleep(1)
    i = i + 1
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print ("received message:" + data)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is different in your setup. But your code works for me without changes (apart from local and target IP). Both clients on same Linux machine behind NAT, server on Linux machine too. There is one interesting thing though: one of your clients binds to the local IP while the other binds to 0.0.0.0. Depending on your OS this might make a difference. I suggest to bind both clients not only to the same port but also to the same IP.

Comment: No its binded both clients to '0.0.0.0'. Why do you say both are bound to different IP, one to local, other to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: @Ouroboros: no, the first client is  not bound to 0.0.0.0. At least I've interpreted  `UDP_IP = '0.0.0.0'#my ip address in the local network` as an order to replace the actual IP there.

Comment: I'm using linux on both machines, and most likely there's no firewall (Client is on Raspian OS on pi)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm able to receive the packets after putting the local IP Address as you said in client_recv. Why didn't 0.0.0.0 work? Can you tell me what was happening when I put the local IP vs 0.0.0.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;TR: the problem is unrelated to NAT. It is instead about less specific vs,. more specific bindings on sockets.

You have two clients on the same system:

- client_recv.pl is bound to 0.0.0.0:
  `UDP_IP = '0.0.0.0'#my ip address in the local network`
- client_send.pl is initially explicitly bound to 0.0.0.0 too:
  `sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5000))`
  But  the socket will be internally re-bound to the outgoing IP of your local system in order to send the packet with the correct outgoing IP address::
  `sock.sendto(MESSAGE + ' # ' + str(i), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))`
  Note that you cannot see this new binding in netstat, it seems to be deeper in the kernel.

This means you end up with two sockets:

- client_recv.pl has a socket bound to 0.0.0.0:5000
- client_send.pl has a socket bound to your-local-ip:5000

If a packet arrives from the server it goes to the most specific socket, i.e. the one from client_send.pl. Thus client_recv.pl never receives the packet.

If you instead change the IP address in client_recv.pl to the  IP of your local system you get two sockets, both bound to `your-local-ip:5000`. Since there is no most specific socket in this case the packet is actually delivered to the first one which reads it, in your case `client_recv.pl`.

Comment: Brilliant reasoning. I get this thing completely now. Re-Binding to local IP and sending to most specific socket is new to me. Any simple to understand link which point to that?

Comment: Accepting the answer. Link to documentation if any supporting what you say?

Comment: @steffen : If I write such a program on client, where say the local IP address keeps on changing (Say the internet connection is flaky/AP hopping keeps changing the local IP Address), in that case would the client_recv also need to be restarted with the correct local IP every time the local IP changes?

Comment: @Jamboree: actually I don't know any source about this internal rebinding. I draw this conclusion only from the fact that the packet gets delivered with the IP address of the system and not with the one it was bound to, i.e. `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: @Ouroboros: Unfortunately I'm not sure about this. But it might be that the internal binding automatically gets updated. Worth a try.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Unlikely that internal binding would change automatically because the IP Address has changed. Let me try and let you know my finding

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Just confirmed that client_recv stops working, and then the only way to make it work is to restart the process.