# Cannot receive UDP when different sockets bind to same port

Tags: udp, port, nat

Came across an interesting observation in a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48782151/udp-client-across-nat-could-not-receive-data-from-server), where there are two client processes (client is across NAT) which both bind locally to same port (reusing port), use UDP socket to send data in one process, and receive in another.
It turns out, the receive process could not receive the data.

Client Process (Send) --- Port 5000 ---> NAT --Port 5333 (say) -> Server

*This works*

Server ----Port(5333)--->   NAT  ---Port??---> Client Process (Recv)

*This doesnt work*

It seems if a single client process with same socket is used for both send and receive, it receives the data from server.

Why this behavior? If both client send and receive processes were bind to the same port, things should have worked?

Why is different process causing this behavior? Looks like due to different processes, different port are used despite port reuse?

Comment: Ummm the middle Nat port doesn't have to be staic... it depends on the Nat implementation...

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: It means port x may not always be port x. Nuff said

Comment: @Jay Can you explain the behavior why it works when send and receive is happening on same socket then?

Comment: Lol yea... so can u.... think about it

Comment: Well, it would help massively if you could point my silly mistake, but I'm somehow convinced this should have worked. Could you please explain

Comment: The code from the question you mention actually works for me (yes, with NAT) which kind of makes this question here moot. And I've left also a comment there why it might not work for the OP.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich : Jay does not seem to agree with you. And my results certainly don't match yours. One difference is my Client is behind a double NAT. But are you certain the code worked for you with client_send, client_recv and server_send_recv?

Comment: @Ouroboros: it worked with the provided source code, only replaced the local and remote IP address at the given places. See my comment there.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Very interesting, setting the local IP address does the trick. Any clue why 0.0.0.0 does not work?

Comment: @Jay I think it has nothing to do with NAT, but the IP address that we're binding it to. As identified by Steffen, the problem is solved if we use local IP address to bind in client_recv. Any clue why?

Comment: @Ouroboros: I've described the reason in the answer to the other question. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48794941/3081018.

Comment: Furthermore that aside it doesn't have to follow some semantic for the internal routing, in fact doesn't even have yo use IP or even erhernet..